# Watir slow on nested tables

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, watir, html-table, watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver to scrape from a page with nested table based layout. As an example, I constructed a very small toy site at http://veryslow.staticloud.com/. To search for the innermost table, that contains the elements USSR and Brazil, I use the following code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
r = Watir::Browser.new
br.goto("http://veryslow.staticloud.com/")
reg = /USSR.+Brazil/m
mytable = br.table(:text,reg).table(:text,reg).table(:text,reg).table(:text,reg).table(:text, reg).table(:text, reg)
mytable.text
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to search for these inner tables?
2. Why is it so slow? To actually locate the table (done when I call `mytable.text`), it takes a substantial amount of time. For complex websites with nested table based layout, this is painfully long.

I know the nested table design is a bad idea, but if you have to read from them, is there a faster way to do that?

Comment: Do the terms of service of the site you are accessing allow automated access of the site without permission?  If not, do you have permission?  maybe there is some way to access the site in a mode that makes it easier (e.g. more testable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're using a Regexp to locate elements, we need to do the filtering on the Ruby side as opposed to in the browser itself. That means that for each time you call .table(:text, reg) here, we find *all* the tables inside the containing element, and filter through that in Ruby to find one that matches the Regexp. That's going to be slow, especially with a page like this.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have been able to figure out that xpath is a better way to go about it for known page structures. So, something like

```
mytable = br.table(:xpath,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table")
```

is usually much faster.

Comment: yes but that ends up pointing to a static cell, not a cell based on it's content, which is a much different thing, hence the speed difference.  (it also breaks if the table content changes even slightly)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance to have the developers assign a name or class to the tables, rows, or cells at least based on position or something? or its function in that location?  that would make things far more testable I should think  That way you could do something like look for a cell with the class 'originating_city' and text "New York", etc.   as it is, you have a testing minefield, and if you can't get any developer cooperation to make the thing testable, I'd seriously start updating your resume and looking for a new position before they go down in flames.

In your specific example, you might try making use of .parent   since there is only one cell in the entire table with USSR in it..  but that would work poorly for any other city-name such as brazil.

Then again I doubt your current regular expression driven approach would work with any other city-combination that was possible on that page where some part of that combination was not unique.

Comment: Since this was a scraping, rather than a testing task, there is no question of developer help. I guess it depends on the scenario as I had to scrape from pages of the same structure so the hardcoded xpath made sense to me. I had also used .parent, but it was much slower than the hard coded xpath.

Answer (score 0):

If looking for the text you can read the entire text out of the top table and parse it to what you're looking for. This is how I reduced a lot of overhead in table searches until I realised I couldn't identify empty table cells, now I have to do things the slow way, but it may help you if you're not interested in the position of the displayed text.

Otherwise... not really. Unless something defined an inner table (or its parent/child) that is excluded from the outer table it's hard to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can find any attributes that the table can be found by.

mytable = br.table(:xpath,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/table")

Will work much better and be less brittle if you write it like 
mytable = br.table(:xpath,"//table[@name='sometablename']")

Sometimes UI elements tend to have dynamic id's that change upon every page refresh like for instance id='xyz12345' changes to id='abc475843' upon refresh.  In this case, you can gain speed by parsing the br.html using Nokogiri or Hpricot (Nokogiri is prefered of Hpricot though).